# scalardb debug prints showing `?` for value. Is there an error?

Tags: scalardb

When I executed my query, I see that Scalardb prints contain `?` for values.

```
[debug] c.s.d.s.c.StatementHandler - query to prepare : [UPDATE codingjedi.users SET tx_committed_at=?,tx_state=? WHERE bucket=? AND email=? AND authprovider=? AND firstname=? AND lastname=? IF tx_id=? AND tx_state=?;].
[debug] c.s.d.s.c.StatementHandler - query to prepare : [UPDATE codingjedi.users SET tx_committed_at=?,tx_state=? WHERE bucket=? AND email=? AND authprovider=? AND firstname=? AND lastname=? IF tx_id=? AND tx_state=?;].
```

The values seem to have got added correctly. Is there an error somewhere which I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a debug log and showing a prepared statement given from DataStax Java Driver that Scalar DB internally uses.
Errors will be printed out with error log.